# How to add custom validation on User-Registration-Form by event subscriber in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How to add custom validation method on User-Registration-Form by event subscriber in Drupal 8
Likes: custom validation for email field which accept only origination email address.

Answer (score 1):

To add custom validation to the form, you should not use `Event subscriber`, use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) instead.

In your custom module file (suppose it is **your_module.module**):

```php
function your_module_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'your_custom_validate';
}

function your_custom_validate(&$form, $form_state) {
  $mail = $form_state->get('mail');
  if (...) { // put your logic to validate $mail here
    $form_state->setErrorByName('mail', 'Email is invalid!');
  }
}
```